# Create a function to Impute values form one data frame into another

Tags: r

The NA values in column A should be filled by the A value from the dat data frame and so on for the other variables.

```
id <- factor(rep(letters[1:2], each=5))
    A <- c(1,2,NA,6,8,9,0,6,7,9)
    B <- c(5,6,1,9,8,1,NA,9,7,4)
    C <- c(2,3,5,NA,NA,2,7,6,4,6)
    D <- c(6,5,8,3,2,9,NA,2,6,8)
    df <- data.frame(id, A, B,C,D) 
    df

   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a NA  1  5  8
4   a  6  9 NA  3
5   a  8  8 NA  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 NA  7 NA
8   b  6  9  6  2
9   b  7  7  4  6
10  b  9  4  6  8


dat <- data.frame(col=c("A","B","C","D"), value=c(23,45,26,89))
dat
dat
  col value
1   A    23
2   B    45
3   C    26
4   D    89
```

It should look like:

```
   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a 23  1  5  8
4   a  6  9 26  3
5   a  8  8 26  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 45  7 89
8   b  6  9  6  2
9   b  7  7  4  6
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

I was thinking something like this but I dont know how to connect those data frames in a function...

```
test <- function(i){
df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] <- dat$value

}
test(2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to iterate over the columns and values and use `coalesce()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df[-1] <- map2_df(df[-1], dat$value, coalesce)

df
   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a 23  1  5  8
4   a  6  9 26  3
5   a  8  8 26  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 45  7 89
8   b  6  9  6  2
9   b  7  7  4  6
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

Or same using `replace()`:

```
map2_df(df[-1], dat$value, ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x), .y))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want it in your format

```
test <- function(i){
   df[,i][is.na(df[,i])] <<- dat$value[dat$col==i]
}

test("A")
   id  A  B  C  D
1   a  1  5  2  6
2   a  2  6  3  5
3   a 23  1  5  8
4   a  6  9 NA  3
5   a  8  8 NA  2
6   b  9  1  2  9
7   b  0 NA  7 NA
8   b  6  9  6  2
9   b  7  7  4  6
10  b  9  4  6  8
```

Comment: Great!! But how could I do this with just refering to the numbers of the columns. So I dont have to use characters of the variables?

Comment: That is a little bit of a problem because your dat dataframe has letters as indicators in col. If you know that you have the same structure you could change the function to `dat$value[i+1]` and it will work for indices, `i+1` because you have an additional column in df `id`.

Comment: @ user2974951 if id is in numbers, how could it then be done? id <- factor(1:10)
> A <- c(1,2,NA,6,8,9,0,6,7,9)
> C <- c(2,3,5,NA,NA,2,7,6,4,6)
> B <- c(5,6,1,9,8,1,NA,9,7,4)
> D <- c(6,5,8,3,2,9,NA,2,6,8)
> df <- data.frame(id, A, B,C,D)

Comment: @user11916948 It would still be the same. You do no have the same structure in the two dataframes so you cannot use a numeric index as elegantly.

Comment: if I transpose the dat column, can it work then?      V1 V2 V3 V4
col    A  B  C  D
value 23 45 26 89